# Transitions in fancyBox 3

Tags: javascript, fancybox, fancybox-3

Is it possible to specify which transition to use in fancyBox 3? There are 3 transitions I'm interested in:

1. Open slide/gallery
2. Navigate between slides
3. Close slide/gallery

By default, fancyBox 3 uses different transitions for different types of content.

```
<a href="img.jpg" data-fancybox><img src="thumb.jpg"></a> <!--This will zoom in-->
<a data-fancybox href="#html-content">Open</a> <!--This will fade in-->
<div id="html-content" style="display: none;">
  <p>This content does just fades in.</p>
</div>
```

Look at this [codePen](http://codepen.io/Stadly/pen/ZebOWE) to see it in action, including the navigation transitions. For images we have:

1. Zoom in
2. Slide horizontally
3. Zoom out

For html content we have:

1. Fade in
2. Slide horizontally
3. Fade out

Is it possible to change this default behavior in fancyBox 3? For example to let also images fade in and out? I was not able to find any information on this in the [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/).

Comment: There are currently no options to customize transitions. Btw, what exactly you are looking for? You described current scenarios, but you did not say what exactly you want.

Comment: Thanks, @Janis. I'm most interested in making images fade in and out, instead of zooming. The combination of a few built-in transitions to choose from, in addition to possibility for specifying a custom transition function to use would be optimal.

Comment: Sorry, wait for the next releases for that (you can follow the project on twitter, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of fancyBox version 3.1.20, this is possible through the options `animationEffect` and `transitionEffect`. You can find the documentation [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#options).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm getting this right... but if you want to fade in & out the images (between each transition)  you can trick them by using a bit of CSS, add this to your jquery.fancybox.css:

```
.fancybox-slide.fancybox-slide--image {
opacity: 0;
-moz-transition: all 0.01s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.01s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.01s ease;
transition: all 0.01s ease;}

.fancybox-slide.fancybox-slide--image.fancybox-slide--complete {
opacity: 1!important;
-moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
transition: all 0.25s ease;}
```

And also modify the speed of the jquery.fancybox.js lib to:

```
// Animation duration in ms
speed : 100
```

Disclaimer: I'm just a mortal and this is not the neatest solution, but worked for me (: